# Proving ${u_p \cdot u_q = u_r \cdot u_s}$ if, and only if p+q = r+s

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am still trying to tacle the theory of series on my own. 
My textbook says i should be able to prove that (knowing that $u_n$ is an arithmetical series and that $\forall$p,q,r,s $\in$ N$_0$):

${u_p \cdot u_q = u_r \cdot u_s}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ p+q = r+s

I started by substituting all the elements in "${u_p \cdot u_q = u_r \cdot u_s}$"
  by  ${ap + b  \cdot aq+b = ar + b \cdot as + b}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ p+q = r+s

$p\cdot q$ = $r\cdot s$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ p+q = r+s

Not only didn't i got to prove the asked statement. This also doesn't seem to work, because when you take p=4, q=6, r=12 and s=12 in the first half of the equation you get $4 \cdot 6$ = $12 \cdot 2$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $4+6 = 12+2$

First half of the equation is twice 24 wich is the same but the second half is not the same because 10 $\neq$ 14. 
Can someone tell me where i did something wrong and why the equation i made so far doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: You probably should tell us something about what $u_p$ means.  From what's written so far I'm willing to bet that it isn't supposed to mean what you think it means.

Comment: What are $u_p, u_q, u_r$ and $ u_s$? And what are $p,q,r,s$?

Comment: I added it to the question :)

Comment: tbh i think $u_p$ is something to the powered $p$

Comment: You seem to assume that $b$ is the incremental change (you add $b$ for each step) in each sequence (and you forgot parenthesis in that case), is that stated in the question? Furthermore, are you sure that you mean series, and not sequence, since in the step where you substitute the $u$'s you only consider the $n$:th number in the arithmetic sequence. The series would be the sum of the sequence up to $n$.

Comment: I will try and translate my course as litterally as possible :

Suppose $u_n$ is an aritmetical series. Proof that ${ \forall p,q,r,s \in N_0 : }$  
${ u_p⋅u_q=u_r⋅u_s ⟺ p+q = r+s }$

Comment: Altough i haven't got to the diffrence between sequence and series in this book and i am not even sure if we make a diffrence when it comes to language. So i suppose sequence is even more likely because i don't see a summation of any kind, anywhere in the part of the book.

Comment: @Michelle_B Is it possible that the translation is "geometric" and not "arithmetic"?  Even so, the "only" if implication only holds if the common ratio is not $\pm 1$ and the sequence is non-zero.

Comment: I will ask if the task might be wrong because i think you might just be right. 
It might take a while before i get answers but.. I WILL BE BACK haha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(ap+b)(aq+b)=(ar+b)(as+b) $

$a^2pq+abq+abp+b^2=a^2rs+abr+abs+b^2 $

$a^2pq+ab(p+q)=a^2rs+ab(r+s)$

As you can see, if $pq \neq rs $ it isn't always true